# How can I conditionally extract parts of a bash string.

Tags: bash

I have a bash string which looks like

```
TEST="tags/1.2.3-abc"
```

from which I want to extract the part after the slash, i.e. "1.2.3-abc" if and only if the string starts with the phrase "tags/". If the latter is not the case, I want to the string as it is.

Examples:

```
Input: tags/1.2.3-abc  Output: 1.2.3-abc
Input: 1.2.3-abc       Output: 1.2.3-abc
Input: trunk           Output: trunk
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the substitution operators in Bash.

Try something like:

```
TEST="tags/1.2.3-abc"
echo ${TEST#tags/}
```

You can read more about this syntax here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 0):

Beside cut command you could also use bash string manipulation for your problem

```
TEST='tags/1.2.3-abc';

if test ${TEST#tags/*}; #Test that $TEST contains "tags/*" expression
 then 
   TEST=${TEST:5};      #Re-assign to $TEST the substring after the "tags/"
fi
```

Comment: Did you even try what you've suggested above?

Comment: solved, actually I was day-dreaming, thx @devnull for pointing it out :D

Comment: @anishsane I know, but I think it makes the code more self explaining

Comment: You still need to understand what `${TEST#...}` does, so this code isn't really any more self-explanatory; it's just longer. (Plus, you have to know that `${TEST:...}` means.)